# Scanning phone number for format to send SMS messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, twilio

I have code for scanning phone numbers to put into the correct format and then have the SMS sent to the phone number.  Although, I don't know how to apply this the "best" way.

**In my create method I have:**

```
    if @order.phone_number.present?

          account_sid = '1234567890'
          auth_token = '1234567890'

          client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

          message = client.messages.create(
               from: '+12017541209',
               to: '+120188854064',
               body: "You received Order from #{@order.listing.name} - View it here: localhost.com/order/#{@order.order_token}/order_confirmation"                   )
   end
```

**I then have this code for scanning:**

```
  def clean_number
    number = self.phone_number.scan(/\d+/).join
    number[0] == "1" ? number[0] = '' : number
    number unless number.length != 10
  end
```

The format I need is `11231234567`

```
Whether the text_input is:

1-123-123-1234
123-123-1234
+1(123)-123-1234
etc.
```

Now, the SMS works but I haven't applied the `clean_number` method yet.  Should i be putting this in my model, and then call it in the controller, or have it in the private within the controller?

Comment: Generally this question would likely fall under off-topic "primarily opinion-based". I would suggest though to identify what you are going to be doing with the number validation; that more or less indicates where the method should probably be.

Comment: I want to use `clean_number` to clean up the format so in case someone uses `-` or `()`, includes a `1` or doesn't, that the output is always in the format listed above in the OP.  Even though this is opinion based in one aspect, I am mostly wondering how I should apply this code so it works

Comment: Your logic only works for USA mobile phone numbers (i.e. where the country code is 1). It won't work [anywhere else in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes). Is that a problem?

Comment: I would say that the best way to handle this is by a model validation - and before you say "but I don't have a model for x" use ActiveModel::Model to create one.

Comment: @TomLord I could be wrong but I do believe all numbers start with 1 no matter what.  For instance, all US numbers have it but it's not needed for in US calls.  But calling/texting outside of the US from the US, you will need to use a "1" in front of whatever the number is in order to get outside of the USA.

Comment: @max so a `before_create` do this? So when it's in the DB it's already ready to go?

Comment: @uno I'm not American, but I don't think that's true. A quick google tells me `011` is the USA exit code - so for example, to dial a UK mobile you may enter: `011447712345678`. (`44` is the UK country code, and `7712345678` is a fake mobile number). If your code is *only* intended to work for USA numbers then fair enough. But for phones based almost anywhere else in the world, it will fail.

Comment: @uno no I would use a validation. You can write your own validation methods although writing a validation for international numbers is pretty much impossibe since there are so many variations.

Comment: @max Yes, I just noticed that after looking into it earlier.  The gem i have does have a verification feature i may implement soon/in the future.  For now, I will have it used only for US numbers.  But i at least want to have the format of the field entry change (although, I did test a text entering for example `(123)-123-1232` and the text still worked, guess they automatically ignore non-numbers).  Thanks for the input - will try that out.